# Returning a single value using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to return a value using LINQ but instead I'm returning the actual query.

Here is my code:

```
var email = from p in dbContext.People
            where p.UserId == UserId
            select new { p.Email };
Contact.Email = email.ToString();
```

I want to get the actual email address of the user but instead I'm getting the query string back.

```
"SELECT [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email]
  FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0"
```

Comment: select p.Email. Is the new { .. } necessary?

Comment: Just a quick hint, you can shorten this code to `dbContext.People.FirstOrDefault(p.UserId == UserId);`, assuming that `dbContext.People` derives from `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx). It *returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.*:

```
var email = (from p in dbContext.People
                        where p.UserId == UserId
                        select new { p.Email }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also if you only want the `Email` to be returned you can simply return it and there is no need to use an anonymous type for this purpose.

```
var email = (from p in dbContext.People
                    where p.UserId == UserId
                    select p.Email).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Note that you can omit the `select new { p.Email }` if you **only** want the email and not an anonymous type.

Comment: Also don't forget that FirstOrDefault() will potentially return null if a record doesn't exist, so you need to determine whether it is best for your particular use case to use First() which would potentially produce an exception if a matching record doesn't exist or do a null check before trying to use the returned object.

Comment: This worked thanks. @KyleBurns yes Im doing a null check before this code runs.